# Solving $\cos(2x)=-\sin(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given $\cos(2x)=-\sin(x)$:

A. Solve the equation algebraically for the exact value of the solution(s) on the interval $[0,2\pi]$

B. Verify the answer(s) in part A using ZERO or INTERSECT features of your graphing calculator.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint: $\cos (2x)=1-2\sin^2 x$. Use this and you have a quadratic equation in the variable $\sin x$.

Comment: Since you can't do much with the linear term $ \ -\sin x \ $ , write $ \ \cos 2x \ $ in the form $ \ 1 - 2 \sin^2 x \ $ . You will now have a quadratic equation  in $ \ \sin x \ $ .

Comment: And for the graphing calculator part, there are any number of videos like this one (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tIAtBsfgXxc) to help you, I'm sure.

Answer (score 4):

Recall the trigonometric identity $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2x$. Now we can rewrite our equation in terms of sine.
$$1-2\sin^2x=-\sin x$$
$$2\sin^2x-\sin x-1=0$$
Notice something? This is a quadratic equation in sine, which we can solve for. Let $\sin x=y$.
$$2y^2-y-1=0$$
$$(y-1)(2y+1)=0$$
$$y=1, \ -\frac 12$$
Reverse the substitution.
$$\sin x=1, \ -\frac 12$$
Break this up into two cases.
$$\sin x=1$$
$$\sin x=-\frac 12$$
Let's solve $\sin x=1$ first. I know that one solution is $\frac{\pi}2$. This is also the only solution in the interval $[0, \ 2\pi]$
$$x=\frac{\pi}2$$
Now for $\sin x=-\frac 12$. Using the CAST rule, I know that one or more solutions will be between $\pi$ and $2\pi$. These solutions are $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ and $\frac{11\pi}{6}$.

Therefore the solutions are:
$$\color{green}{x=\frac{\pi}{2}, \ \frac{7\pi}{6}, \ \frac{11\pi}{6}}$$

---

To find the solutions graphically, first move $\cos(2x)$ to the right hand side.
$$0=-\cos(2x)-\sin(x)$$
Replace $0$ with $y$.
$$y=-\cos(2x)-\sin(x)$$
This is the equation of the graph, with the zeroes as the solutions. Here is what the graph looks like:

[image: Graph of $y=-\cos(2x)-\sin(x)$]

The zeroes within the interval $[0, \ 2\pi]$ are $\frac{\pi}{2},$ $\frac{7\pi}{6}$, and $\frac{11\pi}{6}$, which is the same as our solutions.

Comment: What's the app you use? Looks good.

Comment: @BritMiller Search "Free Graphing Calculator" on the Apple Store. It should pop up as the first result. To make sure you find the right one, the icon is of a red coloured parabola with a black background. Enjoy!

Comment: Quite a nice app, thanks!